# SignatureDoesNotMatch error when upload lots of files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm getting an error trying to upload 500 files to S3-compatible object storage with python/boto3.

I wrote a cronjob to detect files in a specific directory and upload those files into S3 bucket with boto3 library. Able to upload 400+ files and it exited with an error of the following. I don't believe it is a credential problem because it was uploading 400+ files before this error.

> boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload 00000432_1081801000_06042019_07042019.pdf to as003a/36437128: An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the PutObject operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details.

```
 # inside a loop of the list of files
 if os.path.exists(filename):
     totalUploadSize += os.stat(filename).st_size
     totalUploadCount += 1
     obj = s3.Object('as003a', s3id )
     obj.upload_file(filename, ExtraArgs={"Metadata": billMetadata})
     os.remove(filename)
```

I faced this even at file around 430 and i need to have it working for 10,000 in a batch with 10 batch a day.

Comment: This shouldn't be related to the raw number of files, and you are correct that it should not be related to the credentials.  Could there be a hidden/unprintable character in the name of that particular file?  I would take a look at the bucket logs and see what this request looks like, from there.

Comment: Michael, you are absolutely correct. i ran the same script on the same data set few times and it exited at the same record. apparently, one of the field in that record have multiple space in a element within the XML file that i transfer to a dict for metadata. after re.sub() the string to remove the extra space. all are good.